# How to specify a condition on which to complete installation with python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, external-dependencies

I'm trying to make a distributable egg with setuptools and my program depends on wget being present, which obviously isn't available in PyPi.  I have a little script which checks for the presence of wget, asking the user to install it and returning -1 if it isn't installed, or returning 0 if it is installed.

I'd like to complete the installation of my program only if my wget checking script returns 0.  How can I do this with setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

Before you call the `setup()` method in your setup.py, you can check if the wget exists, if it does not, then you can exit with a note saying that you need wget as a dependency for your software.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Check for wget
    if sys.platform == 'linux2' and not ((os.path.exists('/usr/bin/wget') or os.path.exists('/usr/local/bin/wget')):
        sys.exit("You need wget binary for this software to work")

    # setup code
    setup(name='yoursoftware',
          version='42',
          data_files = [  # All your setup details
                        (script_install_location, ['somescript.py']),

          )
```

As the other poster explained, if you can accomplish whatever you are trying without wget
and get it via urlretrieve method urllib, then it would be cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need wget for, have you considered writing your own wget-equivalent in python, using the urllib or urllib2 modules?  Then you'll have something that is both cross-platform and under your control, and you'll break your dependency on wget.  Look at the urlretrieve method.